# Forge Viewer: Properties Window

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The Properties window does not populate any properties even though the 2D view has properties info for the selected room

[image]

Here is the function that loads the model. what am I missing?

```
  function loadModel() {
        var initialViewable = viewables[indexViewable];
        var svfUrl = lmvDoc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
        var modelOptions = {
            sharedPropertyDbPath: lmvDoc.getFullPath(lmvDoc.getRoot().findPropertyDbPath())
        };
            
            viewer.loadModel(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One line missing in your code, please try the following instead:

```
var sharedDbPath = initialViewable.findPropertyDbPath();
sharedDbPath = lmvDoc.getFullPath( sharedDbPath );

var modelOptions = {
    sharedPropertyDbPath: sharedDbPath
};
```

However, you should not need to specify the `sharedPropertyDbPath` manually now. You can take advantage of the `Viewer3D#loadDocumentNode` to load the model directly. It will automatically determine the path for you. (started from v7 viewer)

```
const initialViewable = viewables[0];
viewer.loadDocumentNode( lmvDoc, initialViewable, loadOptions )
      .then( onLoadModelSuccess )
      .catch( onLoadModelError );
```

Comment: Thanks Eason! Do you if there is a out of the box extension to enable search on 2D views in v7 of the viewer?

Comment: loadDocumentNode - you beaut! thanks Eason!